# I keep getting errors when I try to use JavaScript array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, methods

I am doing a quiz on JavaScript on repl.it but for some reason I keep getting errors even though I am pretty sure my syntax is correct. I am using array methods from JavaScript MDN.

Can you please point out my mistakes?

Question: add item to front of array.
My code:

```
function addItemToFront(arr, item) {
  // code here
  const newItem = [1, 2, 3];
  newItem.unshift(0);
  return newItem;
}

addItemToFront(newItem);
```

Question: testScores is an array.  Iterate over testScores and compute and return the average.

My code:

```
function averageTestScore(testScores) {
  // code here
  testScores = [97, 100, 80, 55, 72, 94];
  let count = count.length;
  scores = scores.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  scores /= count;
  return scores;
}

averageTestScores(testScores);
```

Question: Return true if num is inside of arr, otherwise return false.

My code:

```
function contains(arr, item) {
  // code here
  const string = ['hello', 'world'];
  if(string.includes('hello')){
    return true
  } else {
   return false; 
  }
}

contains('hello');
```

Question: words is an array of strings.  Return a string that is all of the words concatenated together.

My code:

```
function wordsToSentence(words) {
  // code here
  words = ['hello', 'world', 'computer', 'science', 'Lambda'];
  words.join(' ');
  return words;
}

wordsToSentence(words);
```

Comment: and what works and what not with which error?

Comment: Variables that you are passing in all these methods either don't exists or are not defined.

Comment: So we need to run all your snippets and guess what works and what not?

Comment: Thank you for the hints about the parameters and variables. I was able to figure them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four solutions share the same problem.

You are calling the functions with wrong, nonexistant parameters. The first piece doesn't even need the parameters (they are not used).

Second one, calls the method with an undefined variable.

Third one, ignores the passed variables, so your code can't really work.

Fourth one, calls the method with an undefined variable.

Dude, this is probably some homework, it looks to me, like you should really try to figure this out, as your code has many issues.

If you want to figure out the erros, look at the Chrome console.